# Distortion in Audacity

Tags: audacity

So I have a guitar part that I want to be distorted, but not overpower anything.

I used the Amplify Effect (all the way up), and it sounds great. However, when I turn the track volume down, it also turns down the effect, making it sound as if there was no amplification.

How do I get the amplification to remain on the track regardless of the track volume?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more logical solution, but I would resample the aforementioned track (record the wet signal to a new track) and turn the volume of the new stem down.

Comment: So record the guitar with the distortion to a new track, then turn the volume down? Sounds good, how do I record the wet track to a new track?

Comment: By resampling I meant recording the audio from your distorted track to an empty track. Also, I assume that in Audacity you can't select an existing audio track as a recording source.
My advice is to solo the distorted guitar track at the volume you have the desired effect. Export it to .wav and mute/delete the original track. Import the new track instead. You should be able to retain the distorted sound when changing the volume, because your new track will operate as an unaffected dry signal.